# Java equivalent of CryptoJS.enc.Base64 for encryption

Tags: java, sha256, cryptojs, hmac

've been trying to port some NodeJS code to Java in order to make HMAC signed requests to an API. I've been able to simplify the code to a point were encoding is clearly affecting the output.

Here's my code in JavaScript:

```
var APIKey = "secret";
var secretByteArray = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(APIKey);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", secretByteArray);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
//alert(hashInBase64);
document.write(hashInBase64);
```

Here's the Java Code:

```
try {
        String secret = "secret";
        String message = "Message";

        byte[] secretByteArray = Base64.getEncoder().encode(secret.getBytes());

        //byte[] secretByteArray = Base64.encodeBase64(secret.getBytes("utf-8"), true);

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secretByteArray, "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

**What to use instead of Base64.getEncoder().encode? **

Comment: What's the problem with Java's `Base64` class? What are your actual and expected outputs? For what inputs? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: My Java code uses Base64.getEncoder().encode to convert to Base64.
My JavaScript code uses CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse to convert from Base64.
I need to make those match.
What is Java equivalent of CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse

Comment: `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(APIKey)` is the closest equivalent to Base64 **de**coding (more precisely the conversion of a Base64 encoded value into a `WordArray`, the data type used internally by CryptoJS), i.e. the Java counterpart would be `Base64.getDecoder().decode()`. However, `APIKey` is expected to have a Base64 encoded value and `secret` is not a valid Base64 expression. But most likey this is just a placeholder for a valid Base64 expression.